# Find the point on a line that's closest to an infinite cone

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d

I have two objects:

- A line $L$ defined by one of its points $l_0$ and a direction vector $d$. (I.e. $l_0 + t \cdot d$)
- An infinite cone $C$ defined by its apex $a$, a direction $e$ and a half-angle $\alpha < \frac{\pi}{2} $.

([Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/va2eznmd))

[image]

I want to find the point on the line that is closest to the cone. In the case that the two objects intersect (in more than one point), I would expect the algorithm to return the point that's furthest "inside" the cone.

So far I failed to figure this out myself. Approaches I thought about/tried:

- The point closest to the cone's axis is *not* necessarily the one closest to the cone itself. I found out by finding [a counter-example](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/sqq6e9gm).
- I read about ways to calculate the intersection(s) between a line and a cone, but that doesn't help me in the case that there is no intersection: then I have no clue.
- I thought about finding a formula for cone-point-distance and then substitute my line equation for the point, finding a minimum in that function in regards to $t$. But I haven't found anything that looks like I could analytically find a minimum.

With this, I don't know how to proceed, hence this question. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The case where the line intersects the cone shouldn't be treated as a consequence of the case where it doesn't intersect it.

Comment: Hint (for the non intersecting case) : write the equation of the cylinder with axis the line and radius $R$. The two equations (cone and cylinder) have a single common point for  "the" point at shortest distance.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the $\pi/2$. Your first comment is fair; I mainly just care about the non-intersecting case. Re cylinder: I'm not 100% sure yet how that would help. Then I'd have to free variables, $t$ and $R$, right? But now I'm googling "cone cylinder intersection" which might indeed be basically the same problem...

Comment: For any point outside the cone, we know that the shortest line segment from it to the cone must be perpendicular to the cone. This might provide an alternate way of writing down the (squared) distance from a generic point to the cone that's more analytically tractable.

Answer (score 3):

[animated geogebra figure here](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/snkp2rfu).

[image]

*Fig. 1: Initial cone (C) in violet. "Enlarged cone" (C') in pale blue, tangent to given line (L). We have chosen to take point $B$ at the same altitude as apex $A$. The shortest distance point $S$ on $(L)$ is projected as $S'$ on $z$ axis.*

The equation of the cone is

$$x^2+y^2=t^2(z-a)^2 \ \ \text{where} \ t:=\tan \alpha \tag{1}$$

The issue is equivalent to find a smallest distance segment between the given line and a certain generatrix $AS''$  of cone $(C)$.  It is known that this smallest distance segment is both orthogonal to the line and the generatrix ; if one considers now any cone $(C')$ with the same apex and axis as the initial cone, with half-aperture angle $\alpha'$, the shortest distance segment from line $(L)$ to cone $(C')$ will be contained in the same plane.

The generic equation of such cones is evidently :

$$x^2+y^2=t'^2(z-a)^2  \ \ \text{where} \ t':=\tan (\alpha') \tag{2}$$

Besides, the parametric equations of the line can be taken in this way :

$$\begin{cases}x&=& x_0 + \lambda u \\
y&=& y_0 + \lambda v\\
z&=& a + \lambda w \end{cases}\tag{3}$$

Indeed, one can assume that the origin point on the line has the same ordinate as the apex of the cone (the only case where this is not possible is for horizontal lines ; a case deserving a - simple - separate treatment).

Now, consider among all cones $(C')$ the one which allows to transform the initial problem where the line doesn't cross $(C)$ into an equivalent **tangency issue** for cone $(C')$ : we are going to look for a value of $t'$ such that the generic point of the line (equations (3)) is a **double** point of $(C')$.

Let us express that the point $M$ belongs to the cone by plugging equations (3) into (2)  :

$$(x_0+\lambda u)^2+(y_0+\lambda v)^2=t'^2(\lambda w)^2 $$

giving rise to the quadratic equation in $\lambda$:

$$\lambda^2(u^2+v^2-t'^2w^2)+2 \lambda(x_0u+y_0v)+(x_0^2+y_0^2)=0\tag{4}$$

A double root means annihilation of the discriminant of (4) :

$$(x_0u+y_0v)^2-(x_0^2+y_0^2)(u^2+v^2-t'^2w^2)=0,$$

a condition giving the looked-for value of $t'$ :

$$t'^2=\frac{1}{w^2}\left(u^2+v^2-\frac{(x_0u+y_0v)^2}{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right).\tag{5}$$

The double root condition gives the unique solution for (4) :

$$\lambda_S=- \frac{x_0u+y_0v}{u^2+v^2-t'^2w^2}=-\frac{x_0^2+y_0^2}{x_0u+y_0v}\tag{6}$$

(by taking (5) into account). It remains to plug this value of $\lambda$ into (4) to get the coordinates of the shortest distance point $S$ on the line (see figure).

**Important remark** : As asked by Hosam H, the shortest distance from $S$ to the given cone is obtained plainly by computing

$$d=AS \sin(\alpha'-\alpha)$$

where the half-aperture angle of the enlarged cone is computed in this way :

$$\alpha'=\arccos\left(\frac{\vec{AS}.\vec{AO}}{\|\vec{AS}\|\|\vec{AO}\|}\right)$$

**Remark :** as pointed out by Lukas, there is a case where this method is not applicable : when (4) is not a quadratic equation, i.e. when its leading term zero, i.e., when

$$(u^2+v^2-t'^2w^2)=0 \ \iff \ \text{using (5) : } \ x_0u+y_0v=0$$

Comment: Similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2963191/305862) solved in particular by using lagrangians.

Comment: The last part of the last equation seems weird? How can it be that $\lambda$ only depends on the base point of the line ($x_0$ and $y_0$) plus its direction ($u$ and $v$)? Or am I confusing something?

Comment: In fact there is no problem : when you plug the value of $\lambda$ into the third equation of (3), you retrieve $w$ !

Comment: @JeanMarie It is not clear in your solution how to calculate the minimum distance between the given line and the given cone.  Your solution calculates the point on the given line that is "closest" to the given cone, but what about the corresponding point on the cone ?

Comment: @Hosam H I have sticked to the question asked in the title  : "find the point, etc.". But, in order to give an answer to your question : it suffices to work in the plane $ABM$ defined by the cone's axis and point $M$ ; therefore use 2D techniques : the shortest distance (red segment) is the distance of $M$ to directrix $AE$.

Comment: @JeanMarie You did not explain why finding the auxiliary cone with the minimum value of $t'$ corresponds to the shortest distance between the given line and the original cone.  I've run the formulas here and calculated the distance between the found point on the line and the original cone.  The distance that I calculated is greater than what I obtained with two other methods, my method (which is in the other answer) and your other method (which is described in your deleted answer).  The answers in both of these methods match, and are less than the distance obtained with this method.

Comment: @JeanMarie Is it $\tan(\alpha' - \alpha)$ or $\sin(\alpha' - \alpha)$???

Comment: My bad, you are perfectly right. I fix it...

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry for the delayed answer. This answer indeed seems to be correct and is quite straight forward :) Thank you for the Geogebra link, too. That always helps me. I created a slight variation of that where you can move the line around in 3D, in case thats helpful to anyone: https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/tbttx7kt

Comment: Actually, this does seem to fail when $x_0 u + y_0 v$ is 0 or close to it. In [this example](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/waqepkan), surely the closest point is $B$ or something close to it, right? When that term is 0, then it completely breaks. Am I missing something?

Comment: A first answer to your judicious remark is that I am "authorized" to reason on "quadratic equation" (4) as long as it is... quadratic. Which is not the case if the front coefficient is $0$, i.e., if $u^2+v^2-t'^2w^2=\frac{(x_0u+y_0v)^2}{x_0^2+y_0^2}=0$ (I have used (5)) which is precisely the case $x_0u+y_0v=0$ you underline. Probably more later.

Comment: I did accept the other answer now as that's what I ended up implementing in code and it works nicely. I still wanted to thank you again for helping me and providing valuable answers!

Comment: I have appreciated our exchanges too. As I have made the remark, there is a drawback in the short answer by John Alexiou : what is the ground for finding the solution by using the real part of the solution ; is it provable ? ... I have never seen such an argument before.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**:  This is not the optimal solution of the problem.  The optimal solution is in my other answer to this question.

The equation of the cone with vertex $\mathbf{V}$ and axis unit vector $\mathbf{a}$ and semi-vertical angle $\theta$ is given by

$ ( \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{V}) ^T Q_c (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{V}) = 0 \hspace{30pt} (1) $

where $ r = [x, y, z]^T,  Q_c = \cos(\theta)^2 I - {\mathbf{a a}}^T \hspace{30pt} (1.1) $

while the line is given by

$ \mathbf{P}(t) = \mathbf{\ell_0} + t \ \mathbf{d} \hspace{30pt} (2)$

If $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{P}$ are the pair of points that are at the minimum distance possible, then the vector $\mathbf{P} - \mathbf{r}$ is along the gradient (the normal vector) of the cone, and also $\mathbf{P} - \mathbf{r}$ is orthogonal to the line direction vector $\mathbf{d}$.  Thus, we now have

$ \mathbf{P}- \mathbf{r} = k \ Q_c (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{V}) \hspace{30pt} (3)$ for some $ k \in \mathbb{R} $

$ (\mathbf{P} - \mathbf{r}) \cdot \mathbf{d} = 0 \hspace{30pt} (4)$

The unknowns here at $x, y, z$ of $\mathbf{r}$ and $t$ of the point $\mathbf{P}$.  Substitute what $\mathbf{P}$ is:

$ \mathbf{\ell_0} + t \mathbf{d} - \mathbf{r} = k \ Q_c (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{V} ) \hspace{30pt}(3) $

$ ( \mathbf{\ell_0} + t \mathbf{d} - \mathbf{r} ) \cdot \mathbf{d} = 0 \hspace{30pt} (4) $

We need to eliminate $k$ from the vector equation $(3)$, and this can done by taking the ratio of the components of the respective vectors on either side of the equation, and then cross multiplying.  This will give

If $ \mathbf{\ell_0} = [x_0, y_0, z_0 ]^T $ and $ \mathbf{d} = [d_x, d_y, d_z]^T $, and $\mathbf{V} =[V_x, V_y, V_z ]^T $ , then the above process leads to two scalar equations

$ (x_0 + t d_x - x) (Q_{21} (x - V_x) + Q_{22} (y - V_y) + Q_{23} (z - V_z) ) = \\ = (y_0 + t d_y - y) (Q_{11} (x - V_x) + Q_{12} (y - V_y) + Q_{13} (z - V_z) ) \hspace{30pt}(5)$

and,

$ (x_0 + t d_x - x) (Q_{31} (x - V_x) + Q_{32} (y - V_y) + Q_{33} (z - V_z) ) = \\ = (z_0 + t d_z - z) (Q_{11} (x - V_x) + Q_{12} (y - V_y) + Q_{13} (z - V_z) ) \hspace{30pt} (6) $

The above two equations (equations $(5)$ and $(6)$ ) are quadratic in $x,y,z,t$, and in addition to them we have the quadratic equation $(1)$ and the linear equation $(4)$.

These equations can be solved using the famous Newton-Raphson multivariate root finder, and with only $4$ variables, and quadratic and linear functions, it converges to the solution very quickly (less than $10$ iterations).

However, it should be noted that the Newton-Raphson method returns a root based on the initial guess, and there can be several roots to the above equations, one corresponding to the minimum, while the others corresponding to saddle points, it cannot be guaranteed that we'll get the correct root, and this limits the viability of using the Newton-Raphson method.  The alternative is to use a solver as the ones available on Mathematica, or elsewhere.  I happen to have the source code of a solver of $3$ quadratic equation in $3$ unknowns.  In this case, we have $3$ quadratic equations and $1$ linear equation in the four variables $x,y,z,t$.  The linear equation makes it possible to express the $x,y,z,t$ in terms of three parameters $u_1, u_2, u_3$.  And then the three quadratic equation of $x,y,z,t$ are transformed into three quadratic equations in terms of $u_1, u_2, u_3$.  And these three I can solve with my routine (that I have the source code for).  The result of solving is a list of all possible solutions, which can be up to $8$ different solutions.  Now all the solutions are known at once, and by evaluating the distance function at each of them we can pick the minimizing one.

**Final remark**:  This solution I wrote several days ago, and today I found an alternative method that is much better than the one here.  Please check my other solution, which only requires solving a simple scalar quadratic equation.

Answer (score 2):

With Lagrange multipliers.

Giving the cone $(p-p_0)'A(p-p_0)=0$ and the line $q = q_0+\mu v$ with $\|v\|=1$ we need to find the point $p^*$ such that $\|q-p^*\|$ is minimum. Forming the Lagrangian

$$
L(p,\mu,\lambda) = \|q_0+\mu v-p\|^2+\lambda(p-p_0)'A(p-p_0)
$$

the stationary points are determined by solving

$$
\cases{
(q_0+\mu v-p)'-\lambda(p-p_0)'A = 0\\
(q_0+\mu v-p)'v=0\\
(p-p_0)'A(p-p_0)=0
}
$$

from the first equation we have

$$
q_0+\mu v-p -\lambda A'(p-p_0) = 0 \Rightarrow
(\lambda A'+I)p=\lambda A'p_0+q_0+\mu v
$$

from the second equation we have

$$
\mu = (p-q_0)'v
$$

and substituting into the previous equation

$$
(\lambda A'+I)p=\lambda A' p_0+q_0+((p-q_0)'v)v
$$

but

$$
((p-q_0)'v)v = (v v')(p-q_0)
$$

so we follow with

$$
(\lambda A'+I)p=\lambda A' p_0+q_0+(v v')(p-q_0)\Rightarrow p = (\lambda A'-v v'+I)^{-1}(\lambda A'p_0-(v v'-I)q_0)=\phi(\lambda)
$$

now substituting $\phi(\lambda)$ into the conic we can determine $\lambda^*$ such that

$$
(\phi(\lambda^*)-p_0)'A(\phi(\lambda^*)-p_0)=0
$$

once we have $\lambda^*$ we have also $p^*$. Follows a plot for the case

$$
\cases{
v = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)'\\
p_0 = (0,0,0)'\\
q_0 = (-8,5,0)'\\
A = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{19}{28} & -\frac{1}{7} & -\frac{3}{14} \\
 -\frac{1}{7} & \frac{13}{28} & -\frac{3}{7} \\
 -\frac{3}{14} & -\frac{3}{7} & \frac{3}{28} \\
\end{array}
\right)\\
\lambda^* = 1.08342
}
$$

[image]

Comment: [+1] Interesting redaction with the particular case. But the problem I have experienced is that giving general formulas is a formidable task...

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality, you can place the apex at the origin and orient the coordinate system such that *z*-axis is along the cone axis.

Use homogeneous coordinates to define a ray as

$$ \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z \\ 1} = \pmatrix{o_x\\o_y\\o_z\\1} + t\,\pmatrix{e_x\\e_y\\e_z\\0} \tag{1}$$

where $o_i$ are the coordinates of any point on the line, and $e_i$ are the components of the direction of the line.

In the same coordinate system, the equation of the cone can be described by the quadratic form

$$ \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z \\ 1}^\top \begin{bmatrix} m & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & m & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z \\ 1} = 0 \tag{2} $$

where $m = \cot^2 \left( \psi/2 \right)$ is the conicity of the cone of included angle $\psi$.

Plug (1) into (2) to find the intersection points from the resulting quadratic

$$ t^2 \left( m\,(e_x^2 + e_y^2) - e_z^2 \right)  +2 t \left( m (e_x o_x + e_y o_y) - e_z o_z \right) + \left( m (o_x^2+o_y^2)-o_z^2 \right) = 0 \tag{3}$$

If the line does not intersect, then the real part of the solution for $t$ will describe the closest point.

$$ t_{\rm closest} = \text{-} \frac{ m ( e_x o_x + e_y o_y) - e_z o_z}{m (e_x^2 + e_y^2)-e_z^2} $$

Comment: [+1] for having learned something new ! I hadn't seen this technique of taking the real part in order to get the shortest distance ; I believe you but is it possible to give a proof ?

Comment: I implemented this solution in Geogebra and it seems to work (at least for the non-intersection case, as stated in the answer): https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/rvxr83c9

Comment: @JeanMarie - If there were intersections they would correspond to the real solutions of the quadratic (3). $$t_{1,2} = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4  a}}{2 a}$$ As we approach one solution at a tangent point, the two solutions become one as the discriminate of the quadratic becomes zero. $$t_{1,2} = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{0}}{2 a}$$ And when there is no intersection the solution of the quadratic has two complex values, and the real part (corresponding to the tangent point) is the closest point.

Comment: @John Alexiou Thanks for your answer ; but don't be offended by what I am going to say : as presented, it is an affirmation, not a proof.

Comment: @JeanMarie - I know it isn't a rigorous proof. It is also incomplete because if you study projective geometry you will find that the quadratic form (2) is a measure of distance between points in space and the cone. Only when this distance is zero the points $(x,y,z)$ belong to the surface of the cone. Take any other point where the LHS of (2) is positive and the point will be outside the cone, and if it is negative the point will be inside the cone. If you end up with double the value of some other point, then the point is at double the distance to the cone.

Comment: @JeanMarie - So give any $t$ value describing a point belonging to the ray, the LHS of (2) describes the distance (multiplied by some constant factor). You can minimize the LHS by taking the derivative in terms of $t$ and setting it to zero. The LHS of (2) describes a parabola in terms of $t$ as seen in (3). At the apex of the parabola is the closest point. The apex of a parabola is exactly at $t = -b/2a$.

Comment: The results that I obtained show some discrepancy between my results and the results that you reported.  I don't see why setting the parameter $t$ to $ \dfrac{-b}{2a} $ will minimize the distance between the line and the cone (assuming they don't intersect).  The quadratic form is not the distance or the distance squared between the line and the cone.

Comment: @HosamH - see comment above. The quadratic form is proportional to the distance.

Comment: Suppose you have a cone with $\psi = 90^\circ$, then $Q = \text{diag}\{ 1, 1, -1 , 0 \} $, and suppose you have a point outside the cone at $ p =  (x, y, z, 1) = (0, \sin \theta, \cos\theta, 1) $ where $ \theta \gt 45^\circ$, then the distance between $p$ and the cone is given by $ d = \sin( \theta - 45^\circ) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}( \sin \theta - \cos \theta )$.  Meanwhile, the quadratic form value is $ \sin^2 \theta - \cos^2 \theta $.  This is not linearly proportional to $d$ or $d^2$.

Comment: @HosamH - Based on your comments you might be correct. I will notify the _op_ to remove the accepted mark until I further investigate.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt - Although elegant, the solution I present might not be correct. Indeed when the quadratic form is zero 0, the intersections occur, but otherwise **the quadratic form may not be a linear metric of distance**. The counter-argument is that projective geometry does not have a concept of perpendicular (which defines min. distances). **Please remove the accepted mark** and I will revise or delete this misleading post.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I removed the accepted mark as per your request. I would appreciate you not deleting this answer, but rather editing it to state what's wrong with it (if there is anything wrong with it). I can say that at least in practice, with the inputs my code has to handle, it works well. So keeping this information available is nice. But I understand that this is math.SE and good-enough.SE :P

Comment: "and *not* good-enough.SE"* it's always extra funny if you have typos in your jokes...

Comment: I found an example where this answer is clearly wrong: https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/jeuqmrsf Here, $r$ is a better value for $t$ that I found via a brute force algorithm. You can even see that the point $B$ (from $r$) is clearly closer to the cone than point $C$ (from $t$). Really unfortunate! This solution is so simple.

Answer (score 1):

We have a right circular cone with apex $a$, and axis along unit vector $e$, with semi-vertical angle $\alpha$, and we have the line

$ P(t) = \ell_0 + t \ d $

The (signed) distance from $P(t)$ to the surface of the cone is simply

$ d = \| u \| \sin( \theta - \alpha) \hspace{20pt} (1)$

where the vector $u = P(t) - a = \ell_0 - a + t d $

And, $\theta$ is the **acute** angle between $u$ and the axis $e$, i.e.

$ \theta = \cos^{-1} \dfrac{|u. e|}{\| u \|} \hspace{20pt}(2)$

Expanding $(1)$,

$ d = \| u \| \bigg( \sin \theta \cos \alpha - \cos \theta \sin \alpha \bigg) $

Using $(2)$ this becomes

$ d = \| u \| \bigg( \cos \alpha \sqrt{ 1 - \left( \dfrac{u.e}{\|u\|} \right)^2 } - \sin \alpha \dfrac{|u.e|}{\|u \|}   \bigg) $

And this simplifies to,

$ d = \cos \alpha \sqrt{ \| u \|^2 - (u.e)^2 } - \sin \alpha \ |u.e|  $

Pluggin in $u$, this becomes

$ d = \cos \alpha \sqrt{ (\ell_0 - a + t d ) \cdot (\ell_0 - a + t d) - ( e \cdot (\ell_0 - a + t d ) )^2 } - \sin \alpha \ |e \cdot (\ell_0 - a + t d) | $

Differentiating $d$ with respect to $t$, and equating to $0$, gives us,

$ 0 = \cos \alpha \dfrac{ d \cdot (\ell_0 - a + t d) - (e \cdot d) (e \cdot (\ell_0 - a + t d ) }{\sqrt{ (\ell_0 - a + t d ) \cdot (\ell_0 - a + t d) - ( e \cdot (\ell_0 - a + t d ) )^2 }} - S_1 \sin \alpha \ (e \cdot d ) 
\hspace{20pt}(3) $
where $S_1 = \operatorname{sgn}( e \cdot (\ell_0 - a + t d) ) $

($S_1$ will be $+1$ if its argument is positive and $-1$ if it is negative)

Define the following constants

$ A = d \cdot d - (e \cdot d) ^ 2$

$ B = d \cdot (\ell_0 - a ) - (e \cdot d ) ( e \cdot (\ell_0 - a) ) $

$ C = (\ell_0 - a) \cdot (\ell_0 - a) - ( e \cdot (\ell_0 - a) )^2$

$ D = e \cdot d $

Then the above equation becomes

$  \cos \alpha \dfrac{ A t + B }{\sqrt{A t^2 + 2 B t + C}} \pm D \sin \alpha = 0 $

Hence,

$ \cos^2 \alpha (A t + B)^2 = D^2 \sin^2 \alpha ( A t^2 + 2 B t + C ) \hspace{20pt} (4) $

and this is a quadratic equation in $t$.  To put it in standard form, re-arrange $(4)$ by combining like powers of $t^2 , t , 1$, you will get

$ a_2 t^2 + a_1 t + a_0 = 0 \hspace{20pt}(5)$

where

$a_2 = A^2 \cos^2 \alpha - A D^2 \sin^2 \alpha $

$a_1 = 2 A B \cos^2 \alpha - 2 B D^2 \sin^2 \alpha $

$a_0 = B^2 \cos^2 \alpha - C D^2 \sin^2 \alpha$

**Note that $(5)$ and $(4)$ are exactly the same equation.**

Now, the two solutions of $(5)$ are:

$ t_{1,2} = \dfrac{ - a_1 \pm \sqrt{ a_1^2 - 4 a_2 a_0 } }{2 a_2}$

To validate the two roots $t_1, t_2$ obtained, we have to substitute the roots in equation $(3)$. One of the two roots will be valid (that is, it will satisfy equation (3)) while the other will not. To find the minimum distance, just evaluate $d$ at the valid root.  To find the closest point to the cone, substitute the valid root into the line equation.

I've tested this method against my other method, and found that both methods give the **same** results.

**Final Remark**:

In addition to the above, it is necessary to check first whether the line intersects the cone.  Recall that

$ d = \cos \alpha \sqrt{ (\ell_0 - a + t d ) \cdot (\ell_0 - a + t d) - ( e \cdot (\ell_0 - a + t d ) )^2 } - \sin \alpha \ | e \cdot (\ell_0 - a + t d) | $

So, setting $d = 0$, we have to find if the following quadratic equation has real roots

$ \cos^2 \alpha ((\ell_0 - a + t d ) \cdot (\ell_0 - a + t d) - ( e \cdot (\ell_0 - a + t d ) )^2 ) = \sin^2 \alpha \ (e \cdot (\ell_0 - a + t d) )^2 $

In terms of $A,B,C,D$ defined above, this last equation is

$ \cos^2 \alpha \ ( A  t^2 + 2 B  t + C ) = \sin^2 \alpha \ ( D  t + E )^2 \hspace{20pt}(6)$

where $ E = e \cdot (\ell_0 - a) $

Equation $(6)$ can be re-arranged as follows:

$b_2 t^2 + b_1 t + b_0 = 0 \hspace{20pt}(7)$

where

$b_2 = A \cos^2 \alpha  - D^2 \sin^2 \alpha $

$b_1 = 2 B \cos^2 \alpha - 2 D E \sin^2 \alpha $

$b_0 = C \cos^2 \alpha - E^2 \sin^2 \alpha $

So that the solution of $(6)$ are

$ t_{3,4} = \dfrac{ - b_1 \pm \sqrt{ b_1^2 - 4 b_2 b_0 } }{ 2 b_2 } \hspace{20pt} (8)$

Provided that the discriminant

$ \Delta = b_1^2 - 4 b_2 b_0 \hspace{20pt}(9)$

Is non-negative, i.e. solutions will exist provided that $\Delta \ge 0 $.

If this equation has real roots then the line intersects the cone at values of $t$ equal to the two roots, and in this case the minimum distance predicted by taking the derivative does not apply, because it is a signed distance, meaning that if the line goes inside the cone, then its distance from the surface of the cone at these internal points will be negative.  The most negative distance in this case is the one reported by taking the derivative and setting it to zero.  So in the case, the negative distance is ignored and the minimum distance is taken to be $0$ corresponding to the crossings of the line with the cone.

Otherwise, if equation $(6)$ has no real roots, then the line does not cross the cone, and hence does not get inside the cone, and the distance $d$ will always be positive.  In this case, the minimum (positive) distance and the closest point to the cone are determined by the valid root of $(5)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm afraid that it does not help me, though :( It's probably just my simple-minded programmer brain, but I feel like your answer is missing the last few steps? So equation (3) is the relevant here, right? That still has to be solved for $t$, then I can put $t$ into the line equation and get my point. Could your answer include the already "solved for $t$" equation? I also don't understand the paragraph below equation (3). Again, I appreciate your help, but I have no idea how I would implement your answer in Geogebra, for example :/

Comment: @LukasKalbertodtl Okay,  I will add the details of solving equation (3)

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt I have updated the solution and added the missing details.  Please check and see if my solution is clearer now.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Have I answered your question and resolved your issue?  If so, please upvote and accept the answer.  If not, please do not hesitate to ask about any points that need clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your offer to ask further questions! I will work through your answer as soon as I can. Sadly for me it's not quickly done in 5min, so I have to find time for it. But I haven't forgotten about this :)

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, but I don't think I can validate this answer. This solution as an algorithm is too involved and thus too slow to be practical for my use case. (I have to check millions if not billions of cones per second.) Therefore I will not even fully implement it. I upvoted your answer, but ideally someone with math knowledge should check whether it's correct. Sorry to disappoint, but thanks a lot for your help here!

Comment: Thanks for the upvote.